# How to test two-factor authentication with QR images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently in the process of adding two-factor authentication to a rails app. I added a process that lets users enable two-factor authentication, by using a QR code to verify themselves. I'm using this gem: https://github.com/Houdini/two_factor_authentication, which lets you generate a provisioning uri that can be turned into a QR code. The user can then scan this with apps like Authy or Google authenticator, to get a one-time password.

I'm now at the point where I need to write tests for this, and I therefore need to be able to automate the process of getting security codes from the provisioning uri, without the need to scan it with an app.

So my question is: Is it possible to get the secret key, that you would get by scanning the QR code, programmatically and if so, how?

The app is based on Ruby on rails 5.2.

Comment: Do you have a [Ruby QR code reader](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/QR_Codes)? If so, retrieve the QR code image, read it back in, and test it out by loading it using `Net::HTTP`, Faraday, or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Find a way to read the QR in Ruby. This would most resemble what the user has to do, but may be hard (I don’t know — I've never done it).
2. Generate the 6-digit code (the "TOTP code") yourself. This feels a little more hacky (and dives into some implementation details, I suppose) but is easier to do than option 1.

For option 2, you can use the `rotp` gem (which Houdini uses itself) and the secret key you generate through Houdini.

```rb
secret_key = user.generate_totp_secret

# then...

totp = ROTP::TOTP.new(secret_key)
totp.now # --> the 6-digit code
```

(You can see how Houdini uses the `rotp` gem [here](https://github.com/Houdini/two_factor_authentication/blob/master/lib/two_factor_authentication/models/two_factor_authenticatable.rb#L36-L49).)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The majority of the problem was to find a way to programmatically read QR images, and get a code back. I haven't been able to find a QR reader that could assist me in that. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

When you want to test a feature from a specific gem, in the most cases you can find some clues in the original repo. Popular gems usually are well tested. Take a look here https://github.com/Houdini/two_factor_authentication/blob/master/spec/lib/two_factor_authentication/models/two_factor_authenticatable_spec.rb#L182

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I look at the original repo, and weren't able to find what I needed. Thanks for taking the time to look at my problem.